# Error when I try to open a Jquery Dialog when a partial view is loaded into a Jquery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

On my Asp.net mvc webpage, I have three tabs. The first is for writing a message, the second for choosing recipient and the last for validation.

- On the first main tab, I have a button for open a preview for the message with a Jquery UI dialog popup
- On the second main tab, I load into another tab function, two views for
  charging each of my recipient list.

I don't understand why I get an error "cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialisation; attempted to call method'open'", when I click on my preview button. I've made some test in my script file and I know, that's when I load a view on the second main tab that's the problem occur. I've made theses test :

- Change the calling method
- Call a very simple partialview
- Open a basic dialog
- create another .js file for dialog

If I delete `$('#AlertCreationTabs-1').html(result);` the preview popup works, but I get the error when I put this line back. I don't understand why it's not working.

Script file :

```
$(function () {
    $('#dialogtest').dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        show:'slow',
        modal:false,
    });
    $('#btnpreview').click(function() {
        $('#dialogtest').dialog("open");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#AlertCreationTabs").tabs();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType:'html',
        url: '/Panels/ViewTest',
        contentType:"text/html; charset=utf-8",
    }).success(function (result) {
        $('#AlertCreationTabs-1').html(result);
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#AlertLog_AlertStartDate').datetimepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
});

$(function () {
    $('#AlertLog_AlertEndDate').datetimepicker({dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy'});
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myTab').turbotabs({
        mode: 'vertical',
        width: '100%',
        padding: '0%',
        textColor: '#000000',
        navBackground: '#f0f6fa',
        backgroundColor: '#f0f6fa',
        hoverColor: '#FFFFFF',
        hoverBackground: '#fab300',
        activeBackground: '#fab300',
        navTextShadow: 'off'
    });
});
```

View :

```
<div id="dialogtest">Zogzog</div>
 <div id="myTab">
            <ul class="tt_tabs">
                <li class="active">Composition</li>
                <li>Recipient</li>
                <li>Validation</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tt_container">
                <div class="tt_tab active">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="panel-outerform">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            ...
                            <div class="buttonbox">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="button" id="btnpreview" value="Preview" class="btntemplate" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tt_tab">
                    <div class="panel-outerform">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="tab-title">
                                <h3>Please Choose Recipient for this alert</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div id="AlertCreationTabs">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#AlertCreationTabs-1">IP group</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#AlertCreationTabs-2">PC group</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div id="AlertCreationTabs-1">
                                </div>
                                <div id="AlertCreationTabs-2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        ...
```

EDIT : Ok, now it's working, but I get another error, I wish to launch a Ticker script (jnewsticker) when the dialog is open. I've tried to add this in `opt` :

```
    open:function (event,ui) {
        var separator ...
        var title ...
        var startdate ...
        document.getElementByid('alertdata').innerHTML = ... 
        $('#newsticker_1').newsticker({
            'showControls':false,
        });
   ),
```

I get an error `TypeError:$(...).newsticker is not a fucntion`. Ticker works with classical `$('#dialogtest').dialog...` . I guess that I must call this open event differently

Comment: May not be relevant here but why do you have so many `$(document).ready()`? and `$(function () {` is equal to `$(document).ready()` itself!! Why don't you combine all those into one? Are they in separate file?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, all scripts are in the same file. I've put only one $(document).ready() and it's doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that this issue is specific to `dialog` box since you are calling `open` method on it and may it isn't created by that time. So just try below option once:

```
$(function () {
    var opt = {
        autoOpen:false,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        show:'slow',
        modal:false,
    }; //store your options

    $('#btnpreview').click(function() {
         $('#dialogtest').dialog(opt).dialog("open"); 
         //Pass the options and create the dialog and then open it
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. But I have another problem with it, I have edit my post to explain.

Comment: @mrplume Am sorry but this solution was for the problem you mentioned earlier and as per SO you cannot edit the question and update the problem! You have to create separate question for that problem! and moreover your edit doesn't provide much information!

Comment: I'm sorry, because I see that I forgot to tell you in my edit that I know your solution. I've tried it before, but, this solution works for the popup opening, but not for launching the ticker, that's why I've tried to launch a jquery dialog differently. So Excuse me, and then I will ask another question. This response help me to see how I could open correctly dialogs

Comment: @mrplume.. No a prob!! Anways!! Happy Coding.. :)